# TextInput never gets the focus

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textbox, flex3

I am trying to have a `TextInput` inside a button, but it seems that my button intercept all mouse events before my `TextInput`.

Basically I have a class `BaseButton` like that :

```
public class BaseButton extends Sprite
{
    [...]
        public function addMouseListeners( target : InteractiveObject = null ) : void {
            if ( !target ) target = this;
            target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOverHandler, false, 0, true);
            target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOutHandler, false, 0, true);
            target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
            target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
        }
    [...]
}
```

The class where I want to put the `TextInput` extends `BaseButton`

```
public class AddFilterDropDownListItem extends BaseButton {
    private var _input:TextInput;

    public function AddFilterDropDownListItem() {
        super();
    }

    override protected function setupAssets():void {
        _input = new TextInput();
        _input.height = 40;
        _input.width = 240;
        this.addChild(_input);
        _input.appendText("Add..");
    }
}
```

I cannot edit the `TextInput`, the click event seems to be captured by `BaseButton`. I don't understand why, as a child of `BaseButton`, my `TextInput` hasn't the priority?

I can resolve my problem by adding the `TextInput` by adding it to the parent :

```
override protected function setupAssets():void {
    _input = new TextInput();
    _input.height = 40;
    _input.width = 240;
    parent.addChild(_input);  //<------ dirty solution
    _input.appendText("Add..");
}
```

Can you explain me why it is failing? And how can I resolve it cleanly?

PS: I cannot change the architecture of the project. My class has to extend `BaseButton` and I cannot change `BaseButton`.

Comment: You might have to explicitly set `mouseChildren = true;`, depending on what the `BaseButton` class does by default.  I don't quite understand why you'd want a text input within a button, though - from a UI perspective, that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @weltraumpirat It doesn't make sense to me too... I am new in this project and first time with as3 but I can already say that the project code is horrible... Anyway your solution works like a charm! Thanks. Please make an answer so I can mark it has accepted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BaseButton` class probably has `mouseChildren` set to `false`, which prevents any nested DisplayObjects from receiving mouse events.  Everything should work as expected, if you set `mouseChildren = true;` on your derived class.